# binascii unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, encryption, typeerror

I'm a beginner, sorry is this is obvious or weird. I also apologize if this has been answered before, I just can't find anything that really works.

I'm trying to make a program to encrypt and decrypt text files.

My thinking behind this is to encrypt the characters into number forms, and multiply them as the encryption, and of course divide as the decryption.

The Encryption part works perfectly, but when running the decryption code I keep getting a

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'.

I've tried float and int, but they don't work.

Encryption Code:

```
import binascii

#ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM
algorithm = 2

#ASCII ----> NUMBERS
raw = raw_input("Enter text to encrypt:")
one = binascii.hexlify(raw)
two = binascii.hexlify(one)

#UNENCRYPTED HEX
unencrypted = int(two)

#ENCRYPT HEX
encrypted =  unencrypted * algorithm

#PRINTS ENCRYPTED TEXT
print "%.9f" % encrypted
```

Decryption Code:

```
import time
import binascii

incorrectpasswords = 0
password=("mypass")
originpassword = password
x = 1
algorithm = 2

while x==1:
    passwordattempt =raw_input("Enter Password:")
    if passwordattempt == password:
        print("Correct")
        x = 2

    if passwordattempt!= password:
        print("Incorrect")
        incorrectpasswords = incorrectpasswords + 1
    if incorrectpasswords > 2:
        if x == 1:
            password = (generatedpassword)
            print("Too many wrong attempts, please try again in one minute.")
            time.sleep(60)
            password=originpassword


encrypted = float(input("Enter text to unencrypt:"))
formatted = "%.9f" % encrypted
formatted2 = formatted
one = formatted2 / algorithm
print ("%.9f" % one)
two = binascii.unhexlify(one)
unencrypted = binascii.unhexlify(two)
print(unencrypted)
```

Also, this in python 2.7 as binascii isn't working for me in python 3.

Comment: Because `formatted2` is a string and `algorithm` is an integer. They can't perform a mathematical operation like that. Perhaps you meant to be using `encrypted / algorithm`?

Comment: `formatted2 = formatted` seems rather pointless... Just use `formatted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to divide a formatted string by a number.

```
algorithm = 2

encrypted = float(input("Enter text to unencrypt:"))
one = encrypted / algorithm
print("%.9f" % one)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I'm having another problem though, >TypeError: a2b_hex() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not float. When I try to fix it with a str, and implementing str to the other variables, I get >TypeError: Odd-length string
I'm not sure what that's supposed to mean.

Comment: Since that is a different error, If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.